# Azure storage account container

Tags: azure, containers, azure-storage-account, data-masking

Is anyone aware of a way to anonomise data within a storage account container on Azure?

I was assuming no but wanted to see if anyone had any ideas on this?

I'm aware of **data masking** on SQL databases on Azure but within containers we have files with data that are used within a data lake.

I know my details a little sparse... But I'm still trying to understand the underlying architecture I'm working with atm.

Any questions/ideas/thoughts, throw them at me!

Comment: answered my own question whilst looking into this - I need to find the source data which is within a sql database and anonymise that..

Answer (score 0):

Azure storage account(data lake) don't support data masking. so mask at the source of the data is not possible.

You can create app to mask the data and put it in the same VNET with your data lake(In this way, the others can not access the primary data). And then send the data to target storage.

But maybe what you need is [customer managed keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) to do data encryption？